# R: Function without arguments and without return value?

Tags: r, function

I would like a function in R to just evaluate a few lines of code. I can do it like this:

```
MyFunction = function(x){
  x = rnorm(10)
  x <<- x^2
  print("and dinosaurs are scary")
  y = TRUE
}
```

But I find it a bit ugly that I have to define an inputvarable (`x`) which I don't use and the function returns a value (`TRUE`) which I don't need.

Actually I am looking for the R equivalent of a "sub" in VBA.

Comment: It is not necessary to pass `x`

Comment: More explicitly, `foo <- function() {x <- rnorm(10)}` is a perfectly valid function in R.

Comment: You can avoid visible returns with `invisible()`.

Comment: what's really ugly is your using `<<-` to avoid assigning a returned value.

Comment: But a function like this is *unusual*. It will confuse other users, and (with your global assignment) be dificult to use inside other function and likely cause hard-to-detect bugs if variable names overlap. And it's inflexible in that you can't change the name of `x` that appears in your global environment (or overwrites what's in your global environment) without editing the function. I'd suggest keeping all the code you want to run in a `.R` file *not* inside a function, and just `source()` that file when you want the code run.... seems slightly better on principle.

Comment: Rushabh, joran and Gregor, Thanks for the helpful answers! I will use them.

Comment: Hong Ooi and Gregor, the line with the global variable is of course just an example. I would like to use functions without input and output in several cases, Most of these cases don't involve global variables. And the case that does involve a global variable is quite special; I could not solve it without using one. (Don't have time for details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the advice from Rushabh and Gregor this would be a solution:

```
MyFunction = function(){
  x = rnorm(10)
  x <<- x^2
  print("and dinosaurs are scary")
  y = TRUE

  return(invisible())
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The last line is the same as returning `NULL`. If you remove that line, the behavior of the function is the same.

Comment: @Jonas If I remove the line, the function returns TRUE (value of last expression)., not NULL.